# DbContext Issues Upgrading from .NET Core 1 to .NET 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an older program running on .NET Core 1 and want to get it working with .NET 5. Instead of going through the tedious process of upgrading each version step by step I decided to just create a new solution and start from scratch. Doing this, I am able to copy most files from the older projects.

My issue is in the DbContext classes.

```
public partial class ClassName : DbContext
```

There are a number of errors throughout, but each give me the same (or similar) suggestion to resolve them, relating to a missing using reference.

```
The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Cannot resolve symbol 'DbContext'
```

Now, I know I am missing the `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` reference. So when I add that package to the project, my file changes and I now get about 500 errors (about half the lines in the file).

Some examples of these new errors are as follows:

```
entity.HasKey(e => e.Id)
  .HasName("PK");
    
entity.ToTable("TB");
```

In the above snippet, `.HasName` is throwing the error `'KeyBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'HasName' and no accessible extension method 'HasName' accepting a first argument of type 'KeyBuilder'.`

As someone new to entity framework, am I missing something obvious or should I be re-scaffolding the database to re-create these context files?

Comment: You'll also need to add the [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/) NuGet package.

Comment: Try adding `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`  or one for you concrete database type.

Comment: Thank you both for the response. Adding that resolved those issues and got rid of about 1400 total errors in my solution. Thanks again!

Comment: You may view going step by step as tedious but it often lets you deal with issues a few at a time rather than setting yourself up with hundreds of errors to look at and work out which are real issues.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I get that. But is going from 1.x -> 2.0 -> 2.1 -> 2.2 -> 3.0 -> 3.1 -> 5.0 really the best option in this scenario? I'm basing that path off of the guide in the Microsoft docs. I could see going through each version if I was on 3.0 or 3.1, but coming from 1.0 is a pretty big difference.

Answer (score 0):

No answer here yet so someone might miss that the comments actually holds an answer.

As @Kirk Larkin states in a comment to the question the solution is to add the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` package.